# What are the best practices for implementing timezone handling in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: timezone, symfony-1.4

I'm looking for some guidance to adding timezone handling to a Symfony 1.4 application that previously has not had any.  What are the best practicies?  Is there a good guide or example app that implements time zone handling?

My specific situation...

I'm working on a moderately mature app that uses the Symfony 1.4 framework with MySQL database backend.

The app is a CMS that handles customer tickets, and thus requires lots of timestamping and date handling.  To this point, we have been using datetime fields for storing dates, which does not preserve the timezone.   We have an assumed default timezone of "America/New_York", and the whole company exists in this timezone (until now), so it hasn't been an issue.

I initially added user configs that lets the user set an alternate timezone for their location, and a helper function that gets that timezone and applies it to any date to output that date.  That works for displayed dates.

I'll also need to override form widgets that use times, and before I start over-riding them on my own, I'm wondering if there isn't a better existing method to achieve this.

Comment: This is too broad at the moment, but I'd advise you to think of any natural timestamps as "global" (just store in UTC) whereas user-entered data may well be in a specific time zone. Whether you need to *maintain* that time zone or not will depend on your system. http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/type-choices.html may be useful to you - obviously it's got nothing to do with Symfony, but it should get you thinking in a useful way.

Comment: I did this for a system recently. After some debate we migrated the server data and all server internal times to UTC and convert to and from local time for display and data entry. Finding all the input and output points for dates & times was a pain, but the result is that users in six countries now get consistent local times.